# How can i connect to my home server that runs on a network using DS-Lite from a Ipv4 network?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4, ubuntu-server

I over the past year tryed to put up a home server and beeing able to conect to it from other networks, aspceially to host game servers for me and friends. Yet we always ran into the issue that some of our frinds with older internet conections couldnt simply connect due to what i suspect DS-Lite. We tried to work around it with a method a friend recomended to me in which i use a service called Tailscale to build a network amongst these computers, from what i understand it works like a vpn that connects the pcs among each other. But i want to find a better methode becuase the Tailscale methode requires people to download a software and conect to said vpn in Tailscale.

Before figuring out the tailscale solution i tried to tunel my ip adreess thought a VPS form Ionos with a static public Ipv4 adress which i didnt got to work.

Dose anyone have a idea on how to make such a conection possible without a seperate Programm?
A Vps i got and the server in my network the last pice missing is my frinds (multiple clients) conection to my home server on some way that wouldnt require them to download a spearte programm ?

Thanks for the Help

PS: My provider would want 20 euros extra for a Buissness network for me to get a usable ipv4 and thats to much in my opinoin ....